# MySQL LEFT JOIN to return and not return rows based on value on JOINT table

Tags: mysql

i have a table named `admin_permissions` which lists pages for my navigation.

i have another table `admin_permissions_override` which will override my standard permissions.

here is my current query:

```
select a.* 
  from admin_permissions a
  LEFT JOIN admin_permissions_override b ON a.sequence = b.page_seq
 WHERE a.show_menu = 'Y'
   AND a.parent = ''
   AND (a.global_access = 'Y' OR a.technical_support = 'Y' OR a.sales = 'Y')
```

which works fine, but i want to be able to include my override table, which has the following rows:

```
sequence
page_seq
user_seq
type
```

`page_seq` will equal `admin_permissions.sequence`

`user_seq` will be `'2'`

`type` will be either `'allow'` or `'deny'`

so, if `type = 'allow'` it will override the permissions and return the row and if its `'deny'` it will again override the standard permissions from the above query and not return the row.

i have added the `LEFT JOIN` for this table to my query but im not sure how to make it return or not

`admin_permissions` table:

```
sequence
page
pagetitle
global_access
technical_support
sales
accounts
show_menu
parent
```

Comment: format your question

Comment: can you describe the schema for admin_permissions

Comment: Check my changes for admin_permissions cols and I've updated the query. I missed the table out

Comment: Pro tip: The `*` in your  `SELECT a.*` makes it hard to understand what you're trying to do. It probably also confuses you. Please [edit] your question to show the exact columns you want your query to return. Also, please give the definitions of all your tables.

Comment: at the moment i want to return all columns until i have finished testing, then i will change the query to select only the columns i am using. i was just not sure on including the override table in my query, should i use a LEFT JOIN like i have or just use a `IN` / `NOT IN` in my WHERE clause